# Tests frameworks and tools for SOA Java developments

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, soa

Currently, I'm looking for any experiences or advices about test tools on Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)  Java developments.
Which the bestpratices and best tools for this job ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find SoapUI fairly handy for exploratory testing; they've recently added REST support, although I haven't played with that in detail.  It's also useful for testing performed by QA staff who aren't ready to write tests in a programming language.

That said, for my own needs, I'd use JUnit and a web-service-invoking client library of some kind for consistency.  That client library could be your own, or a simply just a library that knows how to invoke on that kind of web service.

Answer (score 2):

SOAPUI is a very handy tool

www.soapui.org

I think that you can use it to generate junit tests but you can generate and run a test suite for a given wsdl

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be separate the functionality from the transport (the webservice in your case) and test just the functionality.

As you're unlikely to be rolling your own transport layer I think it's safe enough (these days) to assume that will work as intended but make sure you do integration tests as the potential for interop issues still exist.